# How to append an svg loaded by d3.xml into an svg

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, d3.js

Trying to load external svgs in to a dynamically created svg but still access the properties of the loaded svgs. That is why I'm using d3.xml but haven't figured out how to integrate it in to the dynamic svg created with d3.

Code and js console [here](http://jsbin.com/tuzag/1/edit?html,console)
The code produces this svg

```
<svg id = "svgObj">
   <g class = "grp"></g>
   <g class = "grp"></g>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to load circle.svg within each  element so it looks like this

```
<svg id = "svgObj">
   <g class = "grp"><svg id=minus>...</svg></g>
   <g class = "grp"><svg id=minus>...</svg></g>
</svg>
```

I tried the code below but console errors that there is no appendChild method

```
var grps = d3.selectAll( "g" );
img = grps.appendChild( svgNode.cloneNode( true ) );
```

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @helderdarocha explained, you're mixing up your d3 methods with your plain Javascript methods.  That answer gave you how to do it with plain Javascript methods, I'll balance that out by explaining how to do it with d3 methods.

To append a new element within each element of a d3 selection, the method name is simply [`append`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append), not `appendChild`.  The parameter to append is either a tag name (for which d3 creates a new element of that type for each element in the selection) or a function that returns an actual DOM element (the function will get called for each element in the selection with the data value and index as parameters).  Since you're cloning an existing node, that's the version you want to use:

```
var grps = d3.selectAll( "g" );
img = grps.append( function(){return svgNode.cloneNode( true );} );
```

Comment: Thanks again, AmeliaBR. This is the simple syntax I'm looking for. You are definitely dead on in your observation about me mixing my pure java and d3 methods. They're both new to me.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used D3 before but it seems easy to understand. The error message says that Array has no `appendChild()` method. I read the documentation and discovered that the selections return as double nodes (see [Operating on selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-operating-on-selections)) so you would have to add `[0][0]` (which would select the first node) to be able to use `appendChild()`.

This selects the first node using plain DOM and produces no error (and draws a partial shape on the output):

```
var grps = d3.selectAll( "g" )[0][0];
```

Since you need to insert code in each node, you can use `each()` (see [Control](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-control)) like this:

```
d3.selectAll( "g" ).each(function() {
    img = this.appendChild( svgNode.cloneNode( true ) );
});
```

I tested it on your code and it produces a black circle with a white dash in the middle. Is that what you expected?

Comment: One thing to be careful of with this approach is that after running the `each` function, `img` will only point to the *last* image that was added, not to all the images.

Comment: Thanks helderdarocha, yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Very impressive that you figured it out.